# Is it possible to add a RabbitMQ cluster node as a follower to an existing quorum queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have created a RabbitMQ cluster with three nodes `rmq01`, `rmq02`, and `rmq03`. The start-up process involves the latter two connecting to the first's cluster.

At the same time this cluster is starting up, I have several services (micro-service structure) that are attempting to connect to the cluster and define (durable) quorum queues. (Waiting for a successful connection before trying to create the queue.)

The issue I'm having is a service may successfully connect to `rmq01` and create the queue before the one of the other two nodes (or both) connect to the cluster. This leaves me with a quorum queue that has 0-1 followers instead of the desired 2.

Is there a way to add the missing nodes as followers to the existing queue without deleting/recreating the existing queue? Stopping the missing node(s) and starting them up again does not have them join the queue as followers. The only solution I've found is to delete the queue and restart my service to create it again which will not be a viable option in Production.

(All of the nodes and services will end up being run on a docker swarm, in case that matters. Currently still working locally, where I could put a `depends-on` clause to the `docker-compose.yaml` service definitions, but that will be ignored once we go to the swarm.)

If I can't retroactively attach followers to a queue, is my only option to wait for the cluster to be fully operational before starting any of the services? I would rather avoid this approach, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only one queue will be the master in the cluster. If the clients attempt to listen to the queue again, after the cluster is fully joined, they will be redirected to the correct queue/master. AFAIK, existing client connections will never be automatically forwarded to the promoted master queue. If the client app / library has auto-reconnect support, it may be possible to issue a server-initiated disconnect request to ensure the clients synchronize on the proper master queue.

Comment: I'm aware of the master role for a queue within a cluster and understand how the services (clients) connect to the cluster (with requests being forwarded to the master node for consumption). My question is addressing the issue where only 1-2 nodes in the 3-node cluster are a part of the quorum queue (1 master and 0-1 followers). I would like all nodes to be connected to the queue (1 master and 2 followers for the queue).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you where looking for this command:

```
rabbitmq-queues grow <node> <all | even> [--vhost-pattern <pattern>] [--queue-pattern <pattern>]
```

Allows to grow data nodes on a specific set of filtered QQ(shorthand for Quorum Queue).

And this is the full man page https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-queues.8.html#grow